# jQuery - Change dropdown value and submit form

Tags: jquery, forms, drop-down-menu

I have a page with a dropdown where the default value is **Availability**. I would like to change this value with jQuery to be **Newest**. The problem I'm having is it needs to do a postback where basically the page refresh to show content from the selected option. Any clue guys? I don't have to the source and neither the backend, all I'm able to do is manipulating with jQuery.

This what I have tried but it goes in an infinite loop, the page keeps reloading for ever.

```
$('select[name="ctl00$mainContentPlaceHolder$ListProducts$ListSort"]').val('CustomSortExpression').closest('form').submit();
```

Thanks

```
<select style="width:140px;" id="ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_ListProducts_ListSort" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$mainContentPlaceHolder$ListProducts$ListSort\',\'\')', 0)" name="ctl00$mainContentPlaceHolder$ListProducts$ListSort">
 <option value="CustomSortExpression">Newest</option>
 <option value="Availability">Availability</option>
 <option value="Alphabetical" selected="selected">Alphabetical (A-Z)</option>
 <option value="Brand">Brand Name (A-Z)</option>
 <option value="PriceHighestToLowest">Price (Highest to Lowest)</option>
 <option value="PriceLowestToHighest">Price (Lowest to Highest)</option>
 <option value="RecommendedProducts">Recommended</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ehh, if you want the post back then change the code in the code-behind and set Postback to true.

Comment: I don't have access to the source code, neither to the backend. Otherwise I would have done that! Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var select = $('select[name="ctl00$mainContentPlaceHolder$ListProducts$ListSort"]')
if($(select).val() != 'CustomSortExpression')
   $(select).val('CustomSortExpression').closest('form').submit();
```

Comment: This doesn't work as it goes in an infinite loop, the page keeps reloading and reloading. Any idea how to prevent that?

Comment: Oh how can we add a if statement that would = if "Availability" is selected then change it to newest. Thanks a lot!

Comment: change if($(select).val() != 'CustomSortExpression') to if($(select).val() == 'Availability')